# Facing issue with "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "b00e5nh0la" does not exist"

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table as below

```
 Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 asin       | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 appdetails | json                   |           |          |
```

Below is java code to insert values into the table "appcredential_info"

```
String json = "{ \"asin\": "+values.get(0)+", \"appdetails\": { \"app_name\": "+values.get(1)+", \"app_username\":"+values.get(2)+",\"app_password\": "+values.get(3)+",\"service_provider_uname\":"+values.get(4)+",\"service_provider_password\":"+values.get(5)+",\"marketplace\":"+values.get(6)+" } }";
        System.out.println(json);
        PGobject jsonObject = new PGobject();
        jsonObject.setType("json");
        jsonObject.setValue(json);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO appcredential_info VALUES ("+values.get(0)+", ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setObject(1, jsonObject);
        System.out.println(ps);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Values Inserted Successfully");
}
```

But I'm facing issue as column doesn't exist. In error mention column is the value of values.get(0) method.

Can anyone please help me why I'm getting this issue and can suggest a best way to do it ?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding one parameter, but using a wildcard `?` for the second one? I bet your problem goes away once you use `PreparedStatement` properly, and provide **all** the parameters with `setXXX`.

Comment: Kayaman is right. Use a proper parameter for the first parameter as well.

Comment: first column is varchar and second one is json. I set the type values as "json". That is the reason i did so.

Comment: @user3782636 I don't know what you're trying to say, but your code is wrong. Use `?` placeholders for both parameters. A varchar parameter can be provided with `.setString()`.

Comment: @Kayaman, I have only two parameter in my database one is varchar and another one is json. Since Typevalue set as json, I hardcoding the string value. If there is other way to do with my requirement. Please let me know.

Comment: @user3782636 that's only the type for the first parameter. You can have different types of parameters, so your explanation doesn't hold water.

Comment: @Kayaman - Below is the changes I made based on your input but I'm facing different issue.        


 " String sql = "INSERT INTO appcredential_info VALUES (?, ?)";
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setString(1, values.get(0));
     ps.setObject(2, jsonObject);
     System.out.println(ps);
     ps.executeUpdate();"


"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json" - This is the new issue occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper parameter for the first column as well. And you don't really need the PGObject either:

```
String json = ...;
String sql = "INSERT INTO appcredential_info VALUES (?, cast(? as json))";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, values.get(0));
ps.setString(2, json);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

It's also good coding style to explicitly define the target columns in the INSERT statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO appcredential_info (asin, appdetails) VALUES (?, cast(? as json))";
```

Comment: I'm getting error as "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json"

and syntax is printing like "INSERT INTO appcredential_info VALUES ('B00E5NH0LA', cast('{ "asin": B00E5NH0LA, "appdetails": { "app_name": aetv, "app_username":NA,"app_password": NA,"service_provider_uname":NA,"service_provider_password":NA,"marketplace":US } }' as json))" ... Can you please help me out?

Comment: Then you are not creating a proper/valid JSON string. Take your generated JSON string and paste it into: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  and you'll see the errors

Answer (score -1):

I think you should modify your sql String:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO 'appcredential_info' ('asin', 'appdetails')
VALUES ('" + values.get(0) + "', ?);";
```

Comment: There's no need to explicitly specify the columns if you provide values for **all** the columns.

Comment: The point here I think he is missing single quote in the first value. If he provides that parameter with PreparedStatement then it should be fine

Comment: The quote issue is the root cause, but your code shows the wrong way of using `PreparedStatement` since it inlines the parameter.

Comment: You can't enclose identifiers in single quotes in SQL. `'asin'` is a string constant, not a column name. But in general I agree: specifying the column names is good coding style.

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name for correcting me, I usually get confused between ' and `.

Comment: `\`` is invalid for an identifier in SQL as well

Comment: It is valid in MySQL. Now that I know it is invalid in Postgresql.

Comment: @HưngChu MySQL deviates from the SQL standard in that regard. But apart from, the incorrect quote-usage, this is bad advice, because the OP is already using prepared statement, so he should use parameters properly.